# Run a python file from a directory containing .(dot) in linux

Tags: python, linux

I have my python script to the directory location as follows:

`home/star.boy/testout.py`

How can I invoke the file from terminal?

`python home/star.boy/testout.py` isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having dots.

You are not very specific about what does not work, so I suggest

```
python /home/star.boy/testout.py
```

absolute path to your script.

Comment: Hmm... so putting dots won't check for any hidden files? It will take it as one file name right?

Comment: I don't know what out mean, but "hidden" files are filenames starting with `.` and are just hidden for `ls` and some shell operations like expansion.